# Listen Wired Headset Buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, headset

it's possible to handle the Wired Headset (no bluetooth headset, it is very important) buttons in Android? 
For example, if the user press the "Play" button (Receive incoming call), I change a TextView's text (this is a dummy example, not the real mission :) ).

Could somebody post an example code? (if it's possible)

Thanks, IB

Comment: It's definitely possible as there are apps on the market that do this, such as [Headset Button Controller](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton&feature=search_result).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) if you haven't already.  This is likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `onKeyDown()` in your `Activity` and watch for the `KEYCODE_MEDIA_*` family of `KeyEvents`.